# JFileChooser returns CANCEL_OPTION on path error

Tags: java, swing, filepath, jfilechooser

I want to select a directory with the JFileChooser (which is working):

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
int retrival = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
if (retrival == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    //do smth
} else {
    //print error message
}
```

If I select a folder, and add something like "\exisitingFile.txt" to the path textfield like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaYTB.png), it should print an error message, because the file "exisitingFile.txt" is not a directory. But if I do that and click the save button, the value of "retrival" is 1 (which would be JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION). But I don't want the error message to pop up, if the user cancels. I only want it to show up, if the user is entering the path to an already existing file, which is not a directory.

I wonder why "retrival" doesn't hold the value of JFileChooser.ERROR_OPTION (which would be -1), because this is obviously an error and not a cancel action started by the user.

Thanks, jogo

Comment: showOpenDialog perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it handels it like this.
The option i see that you validate it yourself.

But i recomend you using the DirecotryChooser from JavaFx.

```
public class Main extends Application {  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    DirectoryChooser directoryChooser = new DirectoryChooser();
    File file = directoryChooser.showDialog(null);
  }
}
```

It's pretty simple, but Javafx requires a specific thread to run on, so you have to extend your class with Application and put all your code into the start method.

If the rest of your Application is console based or already written in swing you may want to find an other solution.

I sincerely appologise for any typo or grammatical mistake but english ain't ma furst lungage.

Comment: Well that might work, but he did not ask for a JavaFX Application.